# Using jenkins push all folders to remote

Tags: jenkins

Im using jenkins to pull a git repo then deploy all folders to a remote server. But the problem is I want to push all folders including its subfolders which may contain its own subfolder and so on.
I tried to use `**/**/*` for source files filed but it is ommitting some folder specially in sub folders. How can i use push over ssh to push n level of directories and all of their containing files to remote.

Comment: Are you deploying only everything in the git repo? Or files/dirs at the same level of the git repo?

Comment: I have a laravel project which is hosted on git. On jenkins Im pulling the git repo which is pull everything on the same level. I need to push all project's directories and files to remote

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't compressing the topmost repository directory and then scp-ing it to the remote server? Then you can ssh and uncompress and distribute the files.